# Deleted my default keyboard program and I no longer have a keyboard?

Tags: applications, keyboard

I downloaded a keyboard-changing app, but as I used it, everything crashed, so I deleted it from my phone. Bad choice, since the app I deleted was my default keyboard. Now I have no keyboard, and I can't access the "Current keyboard" tab under Language & Input. How do i get my keyboard back?

Answer (score 1):

You should sideload one from your PC and install it via adb or a file browser.  You can download the Google Keyboard from [here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-keyboard/) for example, and should then copy it onto your device to somewhere accessible with a file browser.  You may need to enable Unknown Sources on your device before browsing to the `.apk` and installing it.

If you don't have a working file browser you will need to [install the SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other) and enable USB Debugging on your device (first enable Developer Options by tapping the build number under **Settings → About** seven times).  Then from a shell/command prompt on your device you can run:

```
adb install path/to/downloadedkeyboard.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Google keyboard from Google Play. If the Google keyboard is already installed but broken for some reason, you can try [Google Japanese Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese). It comes with an English keyboard.